# Is strip_tags() horribly unsafe?

Tags: php, xss

I always use `strip_tags` to prevent XSS attacks, but today I saw a post which was telling it's horribly unsafe. As the manual says, it doesn't check for malformed HTML!

Is it true?

What can I do to prevent XSS?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To prevent XSS you need to:

1. **Validate** all user input that you'll process (for example - if id GET parameter should be a number, ensure it is with e.g. PHP's `is_number()` function or using [Filter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) extension). This should not only include GET / POST parameters, but also cookie names, cookie values, HTTP headers, uploaded file names etc. Attackers can manipulate requests in many ways. If you need to accept & display HTML content from the user (e.g. in CMS application) use well-tested [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) library to filter out Javascript & other XSS payload and leave only clean, sanitized HTML.
2. When displaying the value use **contextual output encoding** (sometimes called 'escaping'). There are different rules on how to encode user-supplied value whether it occurs in:

   - HTML context e.g. `<div>{$_GET['id']}</div>`
   - HTML attribute context e.g. `<div class='{$_GET['class']}'>`
   - Javascript context e.g. `<script> var a = '{$_GET['id']}'</script>`
   - CSS context e.g. `<div style='background:url({$_GET['image']})'>`

It's best to refer to recommended rules described in [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Read it thoroughly and adher to it - XSS is [#2 risk](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A2) to web applications today so you really need to protect from it. See also [OWASP tutorial video on XSS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Z9RQSnf8-g&feature=player_embedded).

Comment: You deserve kudos for distinguishing between validation and escaping. If only more than 10 people would do this...

Comment: @Krzysztof, Did miss a close brace in `<div>{$_GET['id']}</div>` and `<div style="background:url({$_GET['image']})">`, or is that valid PHP?

Comment: `is_int` will never work for POST/GET values, since they're always strings. `ctype_digit` or, yes, the Filter extension is what you're looking for. :)

Comment: true, will fix now.

Comment: I used to use HTMLPurifier extensively but found it to be extremely slow (can only process ~3KB/sec), bloated (~700KB minified), not actually standalone, and I don't like that it wants to write to a cache directory. I recently wrote TagFilter (https://github.com/cubiclesoft/ultimate-web-scraper/blob/master/support/tag_filter.php) to deal with those issues and to correctly parse Word HTML. TagFilter is small (~30KB), fast (~2MB/sec), state-engine driven, stream-friendly, and self-contained. Its HTML and XSS cleanup capabilities are on par with (if not better than) HTMLPurifier.

Answer (score 4):

You should use contextual encoding. See the [owasp xss prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). You have to encode differently depending on where the output is. As an example the following input will be missed by strip_tags, yet cause xss if the output is in the value attribute of a html text input:
 " autofocus onfocus="alert(1)